# Why is fold curried?

Tags: scala

Could start value just be a parameter in op argument list ?

Food is defined on List as

> def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1   Folds the elements
>   of this traversable or iterator using the specified associative binary
>   operator.

What would the implications of defining fold as

> def fold[A1 >: A](op: (z:A1,A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1

So in this version the initial value is passed as a value to the function instead of being curried in a separate parameter list.

Comment: The second option means that in each call to the `op`, the initial value has to be passed, which is unnecessary (why would `op` need to receive the initial value in each call?).

Comment: But where would `z` come from, if `op` needs to be called with it but you don't pass it to `fold`?

Comment: @Bergi instead of op: (z:A1,A1, A1)  use op: (A1,A1, A1) , the type A1 is typed at class level . This would work ?

Comment: @Jesper I think I understand better now, using it as a curried function  saves passing it repeatedly within recursive call stack generated by fold ?

Comment: The fact that it's curried also helps local type inference.

Comment: @blue-sky: Still, `fold` needs to take two arguments (a value and a function) and the `op` function needs to take two arguments, otherwise it can't work. It seems you suggest to change that?

Comment: @Bergi why can't the initial value be passed to op function (ignoring fact that this would mean initial parameter is passed with each call) ? I'm not suggesting this is a good thing to do, I'm just attempting to get better understanding.

Comment: @blue-sky: Well, yes, you could add parameters to the `op` function and pass it anything (a counter for example might even make some sense), but you must not remove the `z` parameter from `fold` - otherwise it does not know what to take for the initial value.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov 'our binary function is in a separate argument list, any type information from the previous argument lists is used to fill in the types for our function. So, A and B are fixed to be Int by the first argument list, and therefore we don't need to annotate our lambda's parameters' from http://pchiusano.blogspot.ie/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html?m=1 I think details your last comment

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant.

Comment: @blue-sky Re. "ignoring fact that this would mean initial parameter is passed with each call". If you ignore facts, you can prove (or disprove) anything.

Comment: The uncurried version would be `def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1, op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1`. I'm really confused about how you got to `def fold[A1 >: A](op: (z:A1,A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1` by supposedly uncurrying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking to motivate that particular signature of `foldLeft`, it may be worthwhile to first examine `reduceLeft`.

```
// Slightly simplified to remove the supertype constraint
def reduceLeft(f: (A, A) => A): A
```

`reduceLeft` squishes the entire collection into a single element and it takes as an argument a function that tells it how to squish each new element in the collection onto what it's got so far.

There's, however, a problem. `reduceLeft` is partial. In particular if the collection is empty, `reduceLeft` has nowhere to begin squishing things. So we can make it total, by telling reduceLeft where to begin. So we give `reduceLeft` an additional parameter.

```
def reduceLeftTotal(initial: A, f: (A, A) => A): A
```

Note that if we just glommed `initial` as another argument to `f`, we wouldn't fix the partiality of `reduceLeft`. If `this` is an empty collection, we still blow up.

```
// This doesn't get us what we want. Where does the initial `A` come from?
def reduceLeftNotWhatWeWant(f: (A, A, A) => A): A
```

Okay, now that we've got `reduceLeftTotal`, there's an immediate new avenue for generalization. Why does the thing that we're squishing all the elements of our collection onto have to have the same type as the elements? The answer is it doesn't!

```
def generalReduceLeftTotal[B](initial: B, f: (B, A) => A): B
```

Finally because type information in previous argument lists, but not previous arguments in the same list, can be used to help Scala's type inference, we can reduce the amount of explicit type annotations we need by currying.

```
// And we're back to foldLeft!
def foldLeft[B](initial: B)(f: (B, A) => A): B
```

Comment: Could do with a "TL;DR: it helps type inference"

Comment: @AjahnCharles sort of. The original question (and the later comments) is at its core about the totality of the fold function rather than type inference.

The OP's suggested `(A, A, A) => A` as an alternative input type. That's not a type inference problem, that's a type signature that cannot possibly be total for empty collections.

There's two stages of understanding, first understanding why it needs to be `(A, (A, A) => A)` and then type inference.

Comment: Sorry, you're right; I've summarized for people searching "Why is fold curried?" (like me) and not for the op's full question.